# Linux Mint 12 - How to disable the bottom toolbar (without gnome-tweak-tool!)

Tags: linux, gnome, linux-mint

If I disable the bottom toolbar from gnome-tweak-tool =>shell extensions => bottom panel extension (=>off), the next time I restart gnome it will somehow merge the bottom panel to the upper panel and the result looks awful( the Activities button will be replaced by Menu ...)
I'm used to the default gnome 3 bar so I would love to make it look that way.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple and can be done using Gnome-tweak-tool;
From the same place you disable the bottom bar(shell extensions) you have to deselect "menu extension" , "smart overview extension" and "window list extension"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to do as follows: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/685#single-panel

Comment: But as I said this way of doing the job will merge the bottom bar to the gnome 3 bar and the result is awful